# OpenCV Error: The operation is neither 'array op array'

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to superimpose a given set of images of the same size (the AT&T facial images database). I have written the code to do so, which works as follows:

1. I have assigned the location of the images (for starting I am considering only 4 images).
2. imstack is used to read one image (as a base image) over which the layover (superimposition) will take place.
3. A for loop is run that goes through all the images and adds them to the base image (imstack). This adding is done by using the addWeighted() function with the parameters as the current image (im) and the base image (imstack) with the alpha values as 0.5 respectively.
4. After the loop has run till its completion (all the images are superimposed on the base image) I tried to print the updated imstack as 'compiledimg' by using the imshow().
5. Further I added the option to save the 'compiledimg' file by pressing 's'.

To fix the error what I have tried is to resize the image after every iteration so that the addWeighted() function receives the images with the same dimensions. First imsize (before entering the for loop) is resized as to set a firm base to the first image with the required size that I have taken as (97(rows),113(columns)).

I don't understand why the addWeighted function is not working because I am using the resize funtion to make sure that the size is kept the same after each iteration. Plus, if also tried to superimpose just two of the images and it worked perfectly fine however it does not work when I try to use the addWeighted() on the third image.

Say I used addWeighted on two images img1 and img2 and stored in img3. Now when I tried to use the addWeighted() on img3 and img4 I am getting the error. Even when I have used the resize function on img3.

***Note:*** Initial size of the images is (97 (rows),113 (columns)) hence I am trying to keep the same image size.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import os

fnames =['~/Downloads/1.pgm','~/Downloads/2.pgm','~/Downloads/3.pgm']
imstack=cv2.imread('~/Downloads/4.pgm')

for path in fnames:

  im=cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser(path))

  im=cv2.resize(im,(97,113))

  imstack=cv2.addWeighted(imstack,0.5,im,0.5,0)

  imstack=cv2.resize(imstack,(97,113))

cv2.imshow('compiledimg',imstack)

k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

if k == 27:         
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

elif k == ord('s'): 
cv2.imwrite('compiledimg.pgm',imstack)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As you add each successive image `N`, you normally take `1/N` of that image and `1-1/N` of the existing. So 1/2 of the first additional image, then 1/3 of the next one with 2/3 of the existing, then 1/4 of the next one with 3/4 of the existing. See *"Averaging Images in Photoshop"* http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-averaging-noise.htm

Comment: Okay so the the main issue lies in the noise. Any idea on how I should remove the noise? Without using any programs like 'neatImage' or 'Photoshop' since I want to write a code which does the work.